# If $S\subset U\cup W$ and is itself a subspace, then $\dim S\leq \max\{\dim U,\dim W\}$ ($U$ and $W$ are subspaces)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to decide whether this statement is true or false. I am leaning towards true, as "experimental" evidence seems to point that way, but I'm having trouble actually proving it or coming up with a counter-example. So far all I have is this:

> $S\subset U\cup W$ implies that $S\subset U+W$ and since $S$ is a subspace of $V$, it is also a subspace of $U+W$. Therefore, $\dim S\leq \dim(U+W)$. For the dimension of the sum, we have the following bound: $$\max\{\dim U,\dim W\}\leq \dim(U+W)\leq \dim U+\dim W.$$ Therefore, $\dim S\leq \dim U+\dim W.$

Now, assuming this is true, how do I show that $\dim S$ is actually less than the left bound? This would follow if I could show that $S$ must needs be a subspace of either $U$ or $W$, whichever is larger, but I can't come up with a way to show that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get more than $S \subseteq U + W$: you'll get $S \subseteq U$ or $S \subseteq W$, which proves the inequality in dimensions quite quickly.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $S \not\subseteq U$ and $S \not\subseteq W$. Then there exists some $x \in S \setminus U$ and $y \in S \setminus W$. Note that $x + y \in S$, since $S$ is closed under addition.

Also note that becase $x \in S \subseteq U \cup W$ but $x \not \in U$, we have $x \in W$. Similarly, $y \in U$.

Now, given $x + y \in S \subseteq U \cup W$, we have two possibilities: $x + y \in U$ or $x + y \in V$. In the former case, we get $x = (x + y) + (-1)y$, a linear combination of vectors in $U$, hence $x \in U$, against assumption. In the latter case, we similarly see $y \in W$, against assumption.

In either case, we get a contradiction, hence $S \subseteq U$ or $S \subseteq W$. Thus, $\dim S \le \dim U$ or $\dim S \le \dim W$. In either case,
$$\dim S \le \max\{\dim U, \dim W\}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer!